# how to get Agreement in my custom class

Tags: magento2, class

I am trying to recover the termes and conditions in my class but without success.

Here is my class :

```
class Bvr extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Agreement $agreement,
    array $data = []

     ) {

    $this->_rootDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
    $this->agreement = $agreement;
    // parent::__construct($data);
    }

protected function printSlip($invoice, $order) {

    $referenceNumber = $invoice->getOrder()->getIsrReferenceNumber();
    $aCmsPage = $this->agreement->getContent();


 }

}
```

I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getContent() on null in /var/www/magento21-test2/app/code/acme/BVR/Model/PDF/Bvr.php
```

Is that you know the solution to recover the terms and conditions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to declare the `agreement` variable. In the constructor, we inject the parent constructor classes.

```
class Bvr extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadInterface
     */
    protected $_rootDirectory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Agreement
     */
    protected $agreement;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
       \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Agreement $agreement,
       \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
       \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
       array $data = []
   )
   {
       $this->_rootDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
       $this->agreement = $agreement;
       parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
   }

    protected function printSlip($invoice, $order) {

        $referenceNumber = $invoice->getOrder()->getIsrReferenceNumber();
        $aCmsPage = $this->agreement->getContent();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the synthax is correct but it don't works.

I tried that :

```
$aCmsPage = $this->agreement->getContent();
echo var_dump($aCmsPage);
```

But this returns me NULL
I find nothing in the doc magento2.
Thanks